# Grep command, File truncated

Tags: bash, logging, terminal, grep

I've a `catalina.out` log file which backed up every midnight and created a new `catalina.out` file.

I want to `tail -f` this file. I have a bash script like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

while true do   tail -f catalina.out | grep  --line-buffered "pattern" | xargs -i echo $(date) {} >> output.txt done
```

I run this script using `screen` command. But it works fine for first day. When the file replaced then it not works and nothing output for the following days. In the console is shows "File truncated". Can anyone please help regarding this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log you are tailing is getting rotated.  Use the `-F` flag to tail to get it to follow to the new file after the rotation.

Comment: I have changed the script with `-F` option. But the following day the logging was stopped. Did not help. Any other opinion?

Comment: The new filename to tail is still `catalina.out` right?  The `-F` flag will follow the filename, so if that were changing for some reason `-F` wouldn't work.